# Cocoapods local dependency - Header file not found

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods

I'm trying to setup a local pod dependency. Basically I have a library that's distributed through cocoapods and I'm building a sample application based on this library. I would like to test this library with the sample application before deploying through cocoapods. I tried adding the library as a local pod but now the sample app complains that the header file of the library is not found. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by the header file? and also when you executed pod install, did it install the library successfully?

Comment: check your lib validation `pod lib lint`. and testing repo specs validation `pod spec lint`

Comment: @AubadaTaljo yes it seems to be installed successfully. I can see a group called development pods and thats symlinked to the location of the library. What I mean by headers not found is that I get an error that it cant find the header of the library thats added as a pod locally. TestSample/RoomViewController.h:9:9: 'TestLib/TestLib.h' file not found

Comment: What are the other alternatives to testing pods locally ?

Comment: @pqteru when I run pod lib lint , I'm getting the following errors     
    - ERROR | The `preserve_paths` pattern did not match any file.
    - ERROR | [iOS] The `vendored_libraries` pattern did not match any file.
    - ERROR | [iOS] The `vendored_frameworks` pattern did not match any file.

Comment: Have you tried to open the workspace file instead of the project file? A screenshot to the current error and file navigator in your Xcode project could be helpful

Comment: @pqteru your command helped me alot thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @pqteru for the helpful command. I ran pod lib lint on my library and I got the errors ERROR | [iOS] The vendored_libraries pattern did not match any file. - ERROR | [iOS] The vendored_frameworks . I got the understanding that the vendored_libraries and vendored_frameoworks are my build output framework and a static library. I build the library and copied the .framework and the static library to the same directory level as my Podspec and did a pod install on my sample app and the error was resolved. Thanks @pqteru

Answer (score 0):

you need to refer this solution. i got error same like you and with this my error solved. please refer it.
first use cocoapods command may your pods also have problem.

```
$ pod repo remove master
$ pod setup
$ pod install
```

you need to Check if the pod header files are correctly symlinked in Pods/Headers

[Headerfile missing error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30818505/ios-cocoapods-podmbprogresshud-installed-give-error-stuck-at-analyzing-depen)